# K Prototypes Model giving me a AssertionError: Categorical index larger than number of columns

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I'm working on a K-Prototypes to create a segmentation of our company customer base. Below is my code. I've assigned all categorical variables to catColumnsPos, most of which are binary. However, I did add seven variables that aren't binary. For example, one variable is called Daypart and has values like "Morning Customer", "AFternoon Customer", "Evening Customer." It's when I add the non-binary variables, I get the "Categorical index larger than number of columns" error.

My understanding is you don't have to create dummy variables for K Prototypes. Below the Model code, I'll put the catColumnsPos code just in case it's useful. That said, I've counted the columns twice and they match.

```
##Run K Prototypes Model
kproto = KPrototypes(n_clusters= 6, init='Cao', n_jobs = 4)
clusters = kproto.fit_predict(K_Prototypes_Casual_Segmentation_df_Prepared, categorical=catColumnsPos)`
```

```
#Categorical Variables
Segmentation_Prepared_cat[[ 
                                  
#'BREAKFAST_IND',                           
'CANDY_PURCHASE_IND_MAX',                  
'CASHTRANSACTIONS',                        
'COFFEE_PURCHASE_IND_MAX',                 
'CURRENT_APP_USER',                        
'DEAL_SEEKING_FLAG',                      
#'DINNER_IND',                              
'ENERGY_DRINKS_PURCHASE_IND_MAX',                       
'FOUNTAIN_PURCHASE_IND_MAX',               
'GASDISCOUNT_IND',                                              
#'LUNCH_IND',                               
'OPEN_AIR_COOLER_PURCHASE_IND_MAX',                       
'PRIVATELABEL_IND',                        
'PROMO_IND',                               
'RESTAURANT_PURCHASE_IND_MAX',             
'ROLLER_GRILL_PURCHASE_IND_MAX',           
'SALTY_SNACK_PURCHASE_IND_MAX',            
'UNDET_CUST_FLG',                          
'WATER_PURCHASE_IND_MAX',
'MOBILE_DEALS_CUSTOMER_FLG', 
'LOCAL_CUST_FLG',
'NONLOCAL_CUST_FLG',
'CIGS_PURCHASE_IND_MAX',
'GENERAL_MERCH_PURCHASE_IND_MAX',
'HIGHMERCHIND',
'AFTERNOON_CUSTOMER_TYPE', 
'NIGHT_CUSTOMER_TYPE', 
'WEEKEND_TYPE' 
]]=Segmentation_Prepared_cat[[
                                  
#'BREAKFAST_IND',                           
'CANDY_PURCHASE_IND_MAX',                  
'CASHTRANSACTIONS',                        
'COFFEE_PURCHASE_IND_MAX',                 
'CURRENT_APP_USER',                        
'DEAL_SEEKING_FLAG',                      
#'DINNER_IND',                              
'ENERGY_DRINKS_PURCHASE_IND_MAX',                       
'FOUNTAIN_PURCHASE_IND_MAX',               
'GASDISCOUNT_IND',                                              
#'LUNCH_IND',                               
'OPEN_AIR_COOLER_PURCHASE_IND_MAX',                       
'PRIVATELABEL_IND',                        
'PROMO_IND',                               
'RESTAURANT_PURCHASE_IND_MAX',             
'ROLLER_GRILL_PURCHASE_IND_MAX',           
'SALTY_SNACK_PURCHASE_IND_MAX',            
'UNDET_CUST_FLG',                          
'WATER_PURCHASE_IND_MAX',
'MOBILE_DEALS_CUSTOMER_FLG', 
'LOCAL_CUST_FLG',
'NONLOCAL_CUST_FLG',
'CIGS_PURCHASE_IND_MAX',
'GENERAL_MERCH_PURCHASE_IND_MAX',
'HIGHMERCHIND',
'AFTERNOON_CUSTOMER_TYPE', 
'NIGHT_CUSTOMER_TYPE', 
'WEEKEND_TYPE' 
                 ]].astype(str)


catColumnsPos = [Segmentation_Prepared_cat.columns.get_loc(col) for col in list(Segmentation_Prepared_cat.select_dtypes('object', 'category').columns)]
```

I want to run the model using several categorical variables that aren't binary variables. My understanding is i don't need to create dummy variables for these, however, I get the error only when they are included.